# `nft flush ruleset` can't delete all rules permanently?

Tags: nftables

List all ruleset currently:

```
sudo nft list ruleset
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        iif "lo" accept
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
```

Delete all ruleset:

```
sudo nft flush ruleset
```

List the ruleset again:

```
sudo nft list ruleset   
#nothing shown on the output
```

Reboot pc and list all ruleset:

```
sudo nft list ruleset
table inet filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        iif "lo" accept
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }
}
```

I draw the conclusion that `nft flush ruleset` can't delete all rules permanently,how to delete all ruleset permanently then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said

> Reboot pc and list all ruleset:

Check if `/etc/nftables.conf` exist, you should empty or delete that too and then run `nft flush ruleset`.

Depending on your distro, you may want to get rid of packages like `netfilter-persistent` if you don't want them *at all*.